# Идемпотентность HTTP запросов

Tags: http, запрос

Я так понял, что запрос называется идемпотентным, если мы зафиксировали состояние сервера, после чего шлем запросы, если несколько запросов подряд возвращают одинаковый результат - то метод называется идемпотентным.

Метод `GET` по очевидным причинам идемпотентный, а метод `POST` - нет, потому что каждый раз будет создан новый объект с другим идентификатором.

Тогда возникает другой вопрос, почему метод `DELETE` идемпотентный? Ведь если у нас изначально была запись, то в первый запрос мы ее удалим, а во второй уже будет возвращена ошибка. И где же тут одинаковый результат?

И, дополнительно, почему метод `PATCH` неидемпотентный? Здесь казалось бы, обратная ситуация, мы новый объект не создаем, а изменяем имеющийся, значит при изменении одного атрибута мы всегда будем получать один и тот же объект с измененным атрибутом.

Почему так?

Comment: У вас неправильное представление об идемпотентности. Идемпотентность означает, что повторный запрос **не изменит состояние системы**. Если вы отошлёте второй DELETE — на сервере ничего не поменяется, потому что запись уже и так удалена, поэтому DELETE идемпотентный. Идемпотентность PATCH зависит то того, как вы его реализуете: если вы сделаете запрос на изменение вида «прибавить 1 к числу в записи», то, очевидно, число будет меняться всегда и никакой идемпотентности не получается

Comment: Связанные вопросы на enSO: [про DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088350), [про PATCH](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260818)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо большое, теперь понятно